# Formulario con restricciones

Tags: html, formularios

El planteamiento es hacer un formulario en el cual se planteen unas votaciones.
En primer lugar hay 1 candidato a presidente, y luego hay varios candidatos a vocales.

Las restricciones son las siguientes:

- Para la elección del presidente se tiene que poder escoger entre el candidato o voto en blanco.

Para ello he pensado que con un input select, ya que me limita la elección a uno u otro.

- Para la elección de vocales se tiene que poder elegir un máximo de 2 vocales o voto en blanco.

Esto es lo que no sé cómo hacerlo, ya que el input select solo me deja elegir uno u otro.
Es posible que hayan 6 vocales (o 4) pero tiene que haber esa restricción.

¿Cómo se puede hacer esto? ¿un formulario en pantalla con la posibilidad de elegir tanto a presidente como a vocal? o ¿un formulario en dos pantallas con un botón de siguiente?

No adjunto código porque considero que entendemos la idea del formulario. Si es necesario más información dímelo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de haberme peleado un poco con el código me he dado cuenta que una posible respuesta estaría [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302799/selaccionar-un-maximo-de-dos-checkbox-de-un-grupo). Solo hay que modificar un poco el código y listo. Si a alguien se le ocurre otra cosa, bienvenido sea.